# Spring MVC Homepage Controller

Tags: spring, spring-roo

I have generated some pages using Spring Roo, and I need to show some items from database on the homepage of the application.
So how can I pass model with data to homepage, Roo has added following lines which I have commented out

```
    <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="index"/>
```

I created a new controller using Roo called Home like this

```
    @RequestMapping("/")
    @Controller
    public class Home {
            @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
            public String index() {
                return "index";
            }
    }
```

Now all the pages show Index view, even /login .

Regards and thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Don't map to the "/" url, ***it will match all requests (as you have seen)***.
Edit: According to comments, the highlighted part of the previous sentence is wrong.  The workaround appears to still be valid.

1. In your web.xml file, configure a welcome file (perhaps index.html).
2. Use the index file name the `@RequestMapping` of your index controller (perhaps "/index.html").

Another option if that is not sufficient

1. In your web.xml file, configure a JSP welcome file (perhaps index.jsp).
2. In your JSP welcome file, forward the request to a known URL (maybe /blammy).
3. Map your index controller to the known URL (ex. `@RequestMapping("/blammy")`).

Comment: I wonder why such a simple thing needs all these work around. As I really don't like to redirect or have a prefix for the app. thanks again.

Comment: Also I wonder why <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="index"/>
matches only homepage, where as in controller it will match everything...?

Comment: While this will work, it is not 100% accurate. "/" will NOT match all requests. In your example it will only match all requests to this controller, which I assume you want. To get data from your persistence layer to the model, do as BrandonV suggested below and bring the `Model` into your method signature and add any attributes to it.

Comment: @DwB - in your workaround wouldn't /blammy get called for every URL ending in / where the welcome file is missing e.g. / or /downloads/ etc?

Comment: No.  The container recognizes the difference between "default" uri of '/' and a non-default uri (ex. "/downloads/").

Answer (score 2):

To pass the model data through, add the Model to your method signature.

For your routing issue, try mapping the request at the method level, and make sure there are a matching mappings for your other views.  ie: "/login"

```
@Controller
public class Home {
   @RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String index(Model model) {
        String myData = "I want access to this";
        model.addAttribute("myData", myData);
        return "index";
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't map to the "/" url, it will match all requests

Comment: @Zeronex That is incorrect. I believe you are thinking of the behavior of `<servlet-mapping>`'s `<url-pattern>` behavior. Spring's `@RequestMapping` will match `/` and only `/` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

As I found myself rather confused with mixed comments above, I thought I will write how I got it to working.

1. Commented out    `<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="index"/>` in webmvc-config.xml
2. Created a new controller. I used roo to create it for me. However I realized that it added a few JSPXs associated to the controller. As I didn't require them, I deleted the JSPXs. The controller sample is below

   ```
   @RequestMapping("/")
   @Controller
   public class IndexController {

       @RequestMapping
       public String index() {
           return "redirect:/asas?page=1&size=10";
       }
   }
   ```

You can pretty much call any existing controller method. In my case I wanted it to display certain items which are retrieved from database.

In my research, by adding `@RequestMapping("/")` it **doesn't** force every request to land in this controller. It only happens when you hitting the applications base URI.

Answer (score 0):

For me works by define the request mapping as the default `welcome-file` path:

```
@Controller
public class Home {
        @RequestMapping("/index.html")
        public String index() {
            return "index";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could follow this approach.

In web.xml add the following code and drop the `index_home.jsp` in webapp directory.

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index_home.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

In `index_home.jsp` , add below code:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<body>
<c:redirect url="/redirect"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Finally in the `Controller` , you could add the code below:

```
@Controller
public class HomePageController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/redirect", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void runMethod(HttpServletRequest servletRequest, HttpServletResponse servletResponse) throws IOException {
       // add your logic to show some items from database on the homepage of the application
    }
}
```